# javascript assignment operator (`=`) vs Object.assign

Tags: javascript-objects, assignment-operator

From what I understand from reading [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), `Object.assign` copies the source provided to the target in `Object.assign(target, source)` or creates a new object in `Object.assign({}, source)`.

In the second case (`var newObj = Object.assign({}, source)`) how is this different from `var newObj = source`?

Is the only difference that `Object.assign` only copies enumerable own properties while `=` copies all?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Think in terms of references.

When you do `var newObj = source` then `newObj` is not really a 'new object', it's instead a **reference** to `source`... If you change `source.a` then `newObj.a` is now that new value as well because they are essentially 2 labels for the same object.

Conversely, for `var newObj = Object.assign({}, source);` then it really is a newly object `{}` that has had its properties assigned and is effectively a shallow clone of `source`. If you subsequently change `source.a`, then `newObj.a` is still its old value because it's a whole different object. Keep in mind that this is a **shallow** clone. So if `source.b` is an object `{ x: 'blah'}` and you change `source.b.x` - then `newObject.b.x` will also change because while `source !== newObj` is true, they both contain a reference to the same child property object `b`.